# JavaScript Error when Showing iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am passing values within a url to an iframe - on a coldfusion website. However, the iframe isn't appearing on the page. I have a method that I have used on a previous website, non-coldfusion, and this works perfectly - which leads me to believe that the issue is caused by the site being coldfusion. I have no experience with ColdFusion.

Hopefully, if I show you the code I am using to pull in the iFrame and values, somebody may be able to help me out - which would be greatly appreciated....

```
<script language="javascript">
function gup(name){
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
            if( results == null ) return ""; else return unescape(results[1]);
}
function prepare() {           document.getElementById('EMAIL_FIELD').innerHTML = gup('email');
                               var email = gup('email');
                               document.getElementById('FIRSTNAME_FIELD').innerHTML = gup('firstname');
                               var firstname = gup('firstname');
                               document.getElementById('LASTNAME_FIELD').innerHTML = gup('lastname');
                               var lastname = gup('lastname');
                               document.getElementById('COUNTRY_FIELD').innerHTML = gup('country');
                               var country = gup('country');
                               document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML = "<iframe src='http://webe.emv3.com/tennisexpress/pref_center/Tennis_SP.html?email="+email+"&firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname+"&country="+country+"' width='750' scrolling='no' height='1000' frameborder='0' ></iframe>"; 
                             }
```

The body tag has the following onLoad function:

```
<body onLoad="javascript:prepare();">
```

and the iFrame is called as:

```
<div id="frame"></div>
```

if you use the following url, you will see that the iFrame is not shown:

[http://www.tennisexpress.com/newsletter_signup.cfm?email=grozanski@emailvision.com&zipcode=11206&source=homepage&firstname=Gary&lastname=Rozanski&country=ny](http://www.tennisexpress.com/newsletter_signup.cfm?email=grozanski@emailvision.com&zipcode=11206&source=homepage&firstname=gary&lastname=Rozanski&country=ny)

Am I missing something obvious? Can anyone recommend any changes?

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) shows a JavaScript error:

```
document.getElementById("FIRSTNAME_FIELD") is null
[Переривати на цій помилці] documen...IELD').innerHTML = gup('firstname');
```

Possibly it's the reason of iframe not being created.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to figure out what the issue is with the Javascript, but at the minute haven't spotted it yet ;(

Comment: Your js code is trying to get the values of elements that don't exist. FIRSTNAME_FIELD doesn't exist in the HTML.